# C# generics - why is an explicit cast needed to from a concrete type back to T?

Tags: c#

This has been bothering me for a while. I'm having a little trouble understanding why explicit casts are needed in the following code:

```
public static class CastStrangeness
{
    public class A
    {
    }

    public class B
        : A
    {
    }

    public static void Foo<T>(T item)
        where T : A
    {
        // Works.
        A fromTypeParameter = item;

        // Does not compile without an explicit cast.
        T fromConcreteType = (T)fromTypeParameter;

        // Does not compile without an explicit cast.
        Foo<T>((T)fromTypeParameter);
    }

    public static void Bar(A item)
    {
        // Compiles.
        Foo<A>(item);
    }
}
```

It seems to me that T is guaranteed to be an A, so surely the compiler could infer that any instance of A is guaranteed to be assignable to T? Otherwise, I wouldn't be able to pass an A or a B into Foo(). So what am I missing?

PS. I've tried searching for endless permutations of keywords on this, but every result seems to wind up referring to covariance and contravariance WRT generic interfaces :)

Comment: "surely the compiler could infer that any instance of A is guaranteed to be assignable to T" Why do you think so?

Comment: As someone below mentioned, T is more specific than A (I hadn't thought of it that way before). I feel a little stupid now, but that little change in perspective was what I was missing.

Comment: BTW, the actual code I was working with was slightly more complicated (and I think perhaps this example code does not correctly demonstrate the problem). I was creating a traversal function for a b-tree, where each node was of type BTreeNode, and it had properties Left and Right of type BTreeNode. The traversal function was wrapping these BTreeNodes into Tuple<BTreeNode, ...> and it required a cast to do so). I could not see a situation where the assignment would fail, which is why I figured an implicit cast should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the case of:

```
Foo(new B());
```

Your first assignment is ok:

```
A fromtypeParameter = item;
```

Since B : A.

But this assignment is not ok:

```
T fromConcreteType = fromTypeParameter;
```

Because you could very well have assigned fromTypeParameter as:

```
fromTypeParameter = new A();
```

Which you obviously cannot cast to T (which is B in this instance). T is more specific than A, it could be derived from A. So you can go one way but not the other, without an explicit cast (which may fail).

Comment: "T is more specific than A".

Thanks - that's the bit I was missing :)

Answer (score 4):

> It seems to me that T is guaranteed to be an A, so surely the compiler could infer that any instance of A is guaranteed to be assignable to T?

Well, no.

`string` is an object.  But

```
string s = new object();
```

is illegal.

Answer (score 3):

All T's might be A... but not all A's are T.

When you create a type that derives from A and pass it into the generic method, the compiler knows it as T, the derived type. If you do not cast it back it does not know that you want A or T, or any type in the inheritance tree between T and A.

This logic applies whether you are using generics or not.

```
public class A
{}

public class B : A
{}

public class C: B
{}

A animal = new C();
C cat = animal;   // wont compile as it does not know that A is a cat, 
                  // you have to cast even though it looks like 
                  // a cat from the new C();
```

Even though you have the generic constraint, this tend to apply to the way the generic method is used and prevents the constraint to be broken. It does not apply to any referencing of a derived type through a base reference. Although the compiler 'could' figure it out it may not know that is what your intent was, so it is better for it to be safe and not infer it.

Comment: Thans, yes - I see now that I was missing the obvious (I think I'd just spent too much time thinking about it, to be honest, and was too close to the problem).

Answer (score 0):

It is less subtle if you use more specific type and variable names:

```
public class Animal
{}

public class Giraffe : Animal
{}

public static void Foo<TAnimal>(TAnimal animal) where TAnimal : Animal
{
    Animal generalAnimal = animal;

    TAnimal possiblyMoreSpecificAnimal = (TAnimal) generalAnimal;

    // The above line only works with a cast because the compiler doesn't know
    // based solely on the variable's type that generalAnimal is a more
    // specific animal.
}
```